# Unable to get Google Maps API to show only UK

Tags: javascript, maps, geo

So I have looked around the site and found the code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'GB'}
};
```

The problem is when I incorporate this into my code I am always obtaining areas outside of the UK when searching (autocomplete). I have tried setting the bounds to around the UK as well but this just does not work either and when i start typing i am seeing USA areas first and the rest of the world. I am pulling my hair out and know it is probably a simple thing I am missing... Here is my code:

```
var GoodIcon = "01a817";
var GoodImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + GoodIcon,
    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
var GoodShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
    new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(12, 35));

var OKIcon = "ff7200";
var OKImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + OKIcon,
    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
var OKShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
    new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(12, 35));

var BadIcon = "ff0000";
var BadImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + BadIcon,
    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
var BadShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
    new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(12, 35));

var GoodLocations = [
    <?PHP
    //obtain only 0 empty ones
    $query = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE empty = 0";
    $data=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $n=1;
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($data);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
        $council=$row['council'];
        $party=$row['party'];
        $empty=$row['empty'];
        $lon=$row['lon'];
        $lat=$row['lat'];
    ?>

  ["xxx", <?PHP echo $lat; ?>,<?PHP echo $lon; ?>, 1]<?PHP if ($n!=$rowcount){ echo ","; } ?>
<?PHP
  $n++;
}
?>
];

var OKLocations = [
    <?PHP
    //obtain only 0 empty ones
    $query = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE empty > 0 AND empty < 100";
    $data=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $n=1;
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($data);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
        $council=$row['council'];
        $party=$row['party'];
        $empty=$row['empty'];
        $lon=$row['lon'];
        $lat=$row['lat'];
    ?>
        ["xxx", <?PHP echo $lat; ?>,<?PHP echo $lon; ?>, 1]<?PHP if ($n!=$rowcount){ echo ","; } ?>
    <?PHP
      $n++;
    }
    ?>
];

var BadLocations = [
    <?PHP
    //obtain only 0 empty ones
    $query = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE empty > 100";
    $data=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $n=1;
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($data);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
        $council=$row['council'];
        $party=$row['party'];
        $empty=$row['empty'];
        $lon=$row['lon'];
        $lat=$row['lat'];
    ?>
        ["xxx", <?PHP echo $lat; ?>,<?PHP echo $lon; ?>, 1]<?PHP if ($n!=$rowcount){ echo ","; } ?>
    <?PHP
      $n++;
    }
    ?>
];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 7,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.945341,-1.148779),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < GoodLocations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(GoodLocations[i][1], GoodLocations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: GoodImage,
    shadow: GoodShadow
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(GoodLocations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

for (i = 0; i < OKLocations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(OKLocations[i][1], OKLocations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: OKImage,
    shadow: OKShadow
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(OKLocations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

for (i = 0; i < BadLocations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(BadLocations[i][1], BadLocations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: BadImage,
    shadow: BadShadow
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(BadLocations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'GB'}
};

new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);


var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
  searchBox.set('map', null);


  var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(49.383639452689664, -17.39866406249996),
      new google.maps.LatLng(59.53530451232491, 8.968523437500039));
  var i, place;
  for (i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
    (function(place) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
        if (!this.getMap()) {
          this.unbindAll();
        }
      });
      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);


    }(place));

  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  searchBox.set('map', map);
  map.setZoom(Math.min(map.getZoom(),9));

});
```

So the part that seems to not work is:

```
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'GB'}
};

new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
```

I have also tried to add the options to the searchbox itself with no luck:

```
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
```

I have also tried UK as the country... Anyone any ideas whats interfering with this or have I got the syntax wrong? Help would be greatly appreciated.